# Oracle Instant Client - SQL*Plus - ERROR: No TNS Listener (MacOSX)

Tags: sql, oracle, macos, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am developing a web application that has to be connected with the ORACLE database.

Presently I am working on macOS X and I have downloaded [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html#ic_osx_inst).
I am able to run `sqlplus`, but while logging in the interface I get the following error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Jul 8 10:55:48 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter user-name: hr
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

For your information, I have downloaded nothing except the client software by Oracle and installed it according to the official installation documentation.
I really need to work on `sqlplus` for the database.

PLEASE HELP.

Also, could you please tell me how can I use `sqlplus` in my machine?

Comment: So you haven't got an Oracle database on your Mac. Do you have an Oracle database on a server somewhere?

Comment: @APC no, and my disk is almost full so i won't be able to run windows or linux using any virtual machine!,

Answer (score 1):

Instant client does not provide you with a Oracle database to work with, they are  just tools to connect to a database.From the documentation of [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html)

> Oracle Instant Client enables applications to connect to a local or
>   remote Oracle Database for development and production deployment. The
>   Instant Client libraries provide the necessary network connectivity,
>   as well as basic and high end data features, to make full use of
>   Oracle Database.

So, prior to using an instant client, you need to have an Oracle database somewhere(local or remote).If you have a database server on a remote host, you may connect it using the easy connect syntax.

```
sqlplus user/pwd@//remote_hostname:1521/remote_dbname
```

If you have a `tnsnames.ora` file in your `$TNS_ADMIN` preconfigured to contain the list of database instances available, you may simply use this to connect

```
 sqlplus user/pwd@tns_entry_for_DB
```

Putting the tns entry in command line also works.

```
 sqlplus user/pwd@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=remote_hostname)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_dbname)))
```

Moreover,Oracle doesn't provide you database software versions beyond 10gr2 to install **locally** on a Mac.

If you want to install and connect to a local database version 12.2 in Mac, One option is to host a  *virtual machine* for Linux/Windows or run a `docker container`. Please read my post here for details: [*Oracle SQL for Mac OS X*](http://qr.ae/TUpdrc)

Comment: Docker's definitely the way to head, but if you're not ready for it, Virtual Box may a stepping stone: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/the-easiest-way-to-install-oracle-database-on-apple-mac-os-x